# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted | DartMessenger | FlutterLocation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Receiving java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted in Flutter Location.java. This is very frequent crash appears in Crashliytics logs.

I have used plugin **location: ^3.2.4**

Didn't find any solution, below is crash logs:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:35)
at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.error(MethodChannel.java:14)
at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocation.onActivityResult(FlutterLocation.java:43)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:25)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:15)
at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:51)
at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterActivity.java:2)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8300)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5353)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5401)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

In above log you can see exception is in `FlutterLocation.java` which is a part of **location plugin**

Comment: Have you seen the crash happen first-hand? Also, without any code, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @PreetShah I have updated my Question. Issue is in location plugin.